# React slick (slider)

Tags: reactjs, slider, react-slick

I have a simple question. (about React-slick)

Input data:

- property slidesToShow: 6,
- total slides in slider === 6

Is it possible to make this slider to make loop? Right now if `slidesToShow` === total slides in slider, then: no loop, no dots, no infinity. Nothing happening.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one help you

```
import Slider from "react-slick";

const settings = {
  slidesToShow: 6,
  infinite: true, // enable looping
  dots: true, // show dots
  // other settings...
};

const MySlider = () => {
  return (
    <Slider {...settings}>
      {/* render your slides here */}
    </Slider>
  );
```

Comment: It don`t, but thanks for trying

Comment: Can you let me know what can you see on your side?

Comment: Demo of  React-slick: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-boyd-sw7mwt?file=/index.js

Comment: Now i`ts fine. but if you will set slidesToShow: 4, then slider will not be working.

Comment: Yes, i can set 3.99 instead of 4, but in this case pagination may not work.